# Прогнозировать объем погрузки на участке железной дороги

Tags: алгоритм, нейронные-сети, big-data, data-mining

Возможно, задача излишне амбициозна, но все же. Имеется участок железной дороги, который обслуживает А предприятий. Каждое из них отгружает один или несколько видов продукции из общего конечной номенклатуры В. Объем погрузки измеряется в тоннах, имеются данные о погрузке по каждому предприятию и каждому виду продукции посуточно за последние несколько лет.

Цель - прогнозировать объем погрузки по каждому предприятию и каждому виду продукции посуточно.

Из исходных данных, которые могут также влиять на объем отгружаемой продукции, могу выделить следующие:

1. размер жд тарифа (чем дороже, тем меньше грузят);
2. цена на каждый вид продукции (причем она иногда влияет прямо: цена на никель упала - грузить перестали; или косвенно: цена на железную руду выросла - стали грузить больше металлолома в качестве заместителя);
3. курс доллара (актуально для поставок на экспорт);
4. сезон;
5. спрос на подвижной состав;
6. проведение ремонтов на инфраструктуре (когда железная дорога не принимает грузы к перевозке).
   Как прогнозируется сейчас: берется опыт прошлых лет по конкретному предприятию и заявки предприятий на предстоящий месяц. Предполагаю, что есть большое количество неявных взаимосвязей, которые человеку тяжело отследить.

Буду рад помощи и советам в построении такого алгоритма, с чего начать. Какой способ построения алгоритма прогноза порекомендуете, возможно, применение машинного обучения?

Comment: Вопрос не столько из области программирования, сколько из области логистики. Так что в первую очередь нужно коммуницироваться со специалистами из данной предметной области. Вообще, то что вы пишете тянет на целый программный комплекс, куда могут входить много разных технологий и алгоритмов. Ну и в одиночку без опыта за такое браться бессмысленно.

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете начать с самых основ машинного обучения: с линейной регрессии.

Дальше можно попробовать разбить задачу на отдельные и обратиться сначала к [SVM](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2), затем уже к нейронным сетям для поиска новых факторов для модели. Очень может быть что ничего, кроме самой линейной регрессии, вам не понадобится.

Порекомендую вам этот [курс по машинному обучению](https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning/home/info). Линейная регрессия с многими переменными рассматривается в одной из первых лекций, но лучше изучать всё по порядку с самого начала. Если вашу задачу в принципе можно решить (у вас достаточно данных), то по прочтении этого курса вы сможете её решить.

Есть общее правило: если задачу может решить человек, то есть предсказать что-то с какой-то, пусть небольшой, точностью из имеющихся данных, то и компьютер тоже сможет это сделать. Если даже человек не может, то тут компьютеру будет сложно.